# Token usage in AWS iOS API

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, token

We are using following API for authentication purpose, Here we are AccessKey and SecretKey however, we do not have a provision to pass Token. These values i.e, accesskey, secret key and token we receive it from our local server .

```
AWSStaticCredentialsProvider *credentialsProvider = [AWSStaticCredentialsProvider credentialsWithAccessKey:AccessKey secretKey:SecretKey];
AWSServiceConfiguration *configuration = [AWSServiceConfiguration configurationWithRegion:AWSRegionUSEast1 credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider];
[AWSServiceManager defaultServiceManager].defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration;
```

Let me know if there is any other API to pass token value as well.

Regards,
Bhat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are referring to AWS temporary credentials, the recommended solution is to build your own implementation of `AWSCredentialsProvider`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26119113/integrating-sts-with-awss3transfermanageruploadrequest-and-awss3transfermanagerd) for further details.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the above facing issue by creating my own Credential provider. Implemented the same methods like Static credential provider class. And i have created extra parameter called token :) . thanks to all .